# Vlookup with 2 text values

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

I'm writing a macro where I need to run a vlookup function where the data in question consists of 9 characters (8 numbers, 1 letter). The problem is the vlookup function doesn't appear to be working properly because both the origin and destination elements are stored as text.

Is there a VBA way of converting text to numbers, or another format that is compatible with Vlookup? The macro runs on a loop and the source data is refreshed each loop cycle so ideally it would be something that worked continuously.

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: What does your Vlookup look like? typically you can only use two ranges to look something up if you do index/match

Comment: Hard to say without seeing your formula and example of your worksheet layout.  As-is, it's not even clear what you're trying to do or whether VLOOKUP is the appropriate formula to use.

Comment: 2 separate tables. The first has 3 columns A, B, and C. The second has 2 columns D and E.  Columns B and D consist of the same information, while the goal is to input information from column E into column C.
Column D and E change based off of the account number in column A (pulling from another program). 
So the goal is, account 1 comes up, columns D and E are populated. macro searches through D, finds the value that corresponds to B, and inputs the value in E into C. Currently: =vlookup(B2,D:E,2, false)

Comment: WHile that is useful information, please revise your **original post** to include that information **AND** example data, so that others who come across this post don't have to read through all the comments to understand what you should've explained initially.  Again, without seeing the data and being able to *test* some things, it is really not possible to give good suggestions.

Comment: You can convert data types in worksheet functions without needing VBA. Take a look at the `VALUE` and `TEXT` formulas.

Answer (score 0):

The CInt function will attempt to convert a datatype argument to an integer. CDbl will attempt to convert a datatype to a double, CLng will attempt to convert a datatype to a long

Example:

```
Public Sub test()
    Dim s As String: s = "1000"
    MsgBox (CInt(s) - 1)
End Sub
```